Clone a folder of a git repository, mapping it to a different local path
Suppose, my remote git repository looks like this:
Repository
├── Folder1
│   ├── p1.py
│   └── p2.py
├── Folder2
│   └── p3.py
├── file1
└── file2

I want to download only the descendants of Folder1, but into a different location. My local repository should look like this:
Folder1             # Local repository root folder
├── .git
│   └── files...
├── p1.py
└── p2.py

This effectively maps Repository /Folder1/** to Local repository root folder /**.

If it's possible, I would also like to commit and push from this partial local repository, but only being able to refresh from the latest version of the remote without any history is also acceptable.
If it's possible, the .git folder should not contain the entire Repository, just Folder1.

I have found several similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of them answered mine. A lot of questions were ~10 years old. Git evolved a lot since then.

I believe you're looking for the functionality of a git subtree. You could have your local repo have the target remote repository, then add that folder as a subtree to your local repo. Work there and commit like usual, then subtree push back to the main repo which takes changes relevant to that directory and creates new commits for the main repo.

git subtree might help, but I think that the commits you are going to make will look a lot different than those made by others who have the complete repository. If this is unacceptable, then it can't be done.

Please, someone give me the commands to issue. I have read about git subtree a little; it seems to be able to download the whole remote repository to a given location, but not only a specified folder. Also, I didn't find its documentation here. Where is it?

If you're looking for docs, then you could use the manpages. Interesting I could have sworn it was in git-scm as well but it is part of the git suite of tools. You would want to look at using the split subcommand on the remote repo, then you could push the split branch to new remote if you want to maintain that separately or otherwise check it out like normal. You will still need to have the commits for the entire repo however, though you could always do a sparse checkout of that to reduce the overall size (depth=1).
